# Cocoa window max size vertically, but not horizontally

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I'd like my window to have contraints on how much it can be expanded vertically, but no constraints on horizontal expansion. From what I can see in the Interface Builder, If you check the box to set max window size, it automatically constrains both. is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to specify a max height without also specifying a max width. However, you can specify a maxSize with a width as high as 9,999.

That's essentially a limitless width, since ["window server limits window sizes to 10,000"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html), at least as of now.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I was planning on doing. just checking if there was a more elegant way.